# How to display an XML file's contents in the exact same layout / format as it was recieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing, loops

I am having some trouble displaying the contents of an XML file in the order it was recieved.

For example, the XML file contains **page** nodes, each page node contains various sub nodes such as **a , b , c**. The layout of the page's sub nodes varies and I need to mimic this layout in the display output.

Example XML file:

```
<page>      
    <a>
        test content...
    </a>
    <a>
        test content...
    </a>
    <c>
        test content...
    </c>
    <a>
        test content...
    </a>
    <b>
        test content...
    </b>
</page>
```

Currently i gather the contents as such:

```
$(xml).find('page').each(function(){    

     $(this).find('a').each(function(){ 
         ...doing stuff here
     }

     $(this).find('b').each(function(){ 
         ...doing stuff here
     }

     $(this).find('c').each(function(){ 
         ...doing stuff here
     }

    }
```

My problem is that by gathering the data using this approach I end up with a display like this:

```
<a>
<a>
<a>
<b>
<c>
```

However what I need is the layout found in the XML file:

```
<a>
<a>
<c>
<a>
<b>
```

So my question is, how can I iterate through the XML file and gather the data in one loop rather than a seperate loop for each sub-node. Essentially, I need the Javascript / jQuery equivalent of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < File.size; i++){

 if(i==<a>){
  do something
 }
 else if(i==<b>){
  do something
 }
 else if(i==<c>){
  do something
 }
}
```

... but where **i** can be a string and not just a character.

Answer (score 0):

Use * Instead of tag name

```
$(xml).find('page').each(function(){    
     $(this).find('*').each(function(){ 
        // ...doing stuff here
     }


    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ubelob/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Champ! I like your style, your answer didn't give me all of the answers, but the push I needed to find them.

```
$(this).find('*').each(function(){ 
        // ...doing stuff here
}
```

Above is exactly what I needed to iterate through the file from top to bottom in the order required... perfect!

My next problem was figuring out how to access the XML nodes along the way, i used "if" cases like so...

```
if(this.tagName == "a"){
    //...do what i need in here
}
```

So in the end my code looked like this:

```
$(this).find("*").each(function(){

    if(this.tagName == "a"){
      //...doing stuff
    }
    if(this.tagName == "b"){
      //...doing stuff
    }
    if(this.tagName == "c"){
      //...doing stuff
    }
});
```

..allowing me to iterate through the selected XML file (or tag within the file) and pick out the data I required along the way, in the order it was read. :)